# Hive action execution parameters setting in Oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I am using Hive Action for executing queries through Oozie. I am setting TEZ and MR as execution engine for queries. How can I set maximum possible number of reducers to execute on for query? Currently, I am using `mapred.reduce.tasks` but it takes a static number.

The real problem is, when I execute same queries on hive CLI, number of reducers chosen by Hive are optimal and not 1; so what setting is my Oozie job missing that it is choosing 1 reducer for all the queries?

Comment: What is the size of the Hive table?

Comment: The size is around 150 GB. But I am running queries on multiple tables, Irrespective of size of table, each job is invoked with 1 reducer only.

Comment: i guess somewhere the reducer count is hard-coded in the Oozie context or hive-site.xml used by Oozie. I suggest you to add `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` property with relative value in the hive script file that you invoke through Oozie.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the ideal way to control the number of reducers of a Hive query is to use the `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` property.

The default value is 1 GB, where for every 1gb size of your input files one reducer will be dispatched.

Try to relatively reduce this value according to the expected maximum number of reducers. By this way you may eliminate setting static number of reducers using the `mapred.reduce.tasks` property.

Comment: Caveat: the default depends on which version you are using; quoting the Apache documentation :"Default Value: 1,000,000,000 prior to Hive 0.14.0; 256 MB (256,000,000) in Hive 0.14.0 and later" -- and then HortonWorks has a ridiculously low default of 64 MB in some HDP releases!

Comment: To set a **max** to the number of reducers (sanity check in case the statistics estimates turn crazy) look into `hive.exec.reducers.max`

Comment: thanks for your suggestions! I have edited my question with more information. Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

When running a hive action in oozie you should always set a configurations property for `mapred.reduce.tasks = -1`.  This will force the optimal reducer value to be created based on your system and available resources.